# Is there a way to automate Visual Studio's Diagnostic Tools (Memory Usage)?

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a way to run Visual Studio's Diagnostic Tools, specifically the Memory Usage tool, from the command line?

What I am trying to do is automate the memory-leak detection process for our regression system.

I have been playing around with Visual Studio's Performance Tools but unfortunately it doesn't seem to track memory.

So the question: how can I automate Visual Studio's Diagnostic Tools?